# Learning RXJS pipe and map

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe

Having tried to use other examples of pipe and map, I'm stuck:
My code:

```
 this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', dto)
  .pipe(
    map(val => {
    return new UserAuthenticatedDto;
    {
      var username = val.username;
      var token = val.token;
      var roles = val.roleslist;
      var knownAs = val.knownAs;
      this.toastr.success("Logged In Successfully", "", { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
      this.route.navigateByUrl('/splashPagePost');
    }
  }));
```

First I don't know if I can invoke toastr, navigateByUrl, etc type functions inside the map (should it be after the map - I don't think there is a way for RXJS operator to execute those)?

It cannot find username, token, etc.  That makes me think these should have shown up in a JSON result?  UserAuthenticatedDto does have those 4 fields.
This can't be that hard, but I try to mimic existing code and it just doesn't fly.
[image]

So BOTH unreachable and not defined.  I tried
map( val : UserAuthentcatedDto => ...   no luck

Ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: All kinds of things wrong with this. If I assume UserAuthenticatedDto is a class.. and the strange thing after that are class constructor params.. it should be something like UserAuthenticatedDto({val.username, ..de rest of those}).. maybe read up a bit more about basic Javascript syntax before you try a more complex thing like RxJs..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with your code. From what you have put together, I could only help you with a little bit of Syntax.

So when you `map`, you are altering your response to a format that you like. In `map` you wouldn't show a toast notification or do any sort of routing.

In `subscribe` you have the mapped data available from the observable (Response for the post request returned from the server in your example).

You would typically handle the toast notifications and routing in subscribe.

```
    this.httpClient.post<UserAuthenticatedDto>
        (urlExtension + 'account/login', dto)
        .pipe(map((response : PutTheTypeOfResponseHere) => ({
                  username: response.username,
                  token: response.token,
                  roles: response.roles,
                  knownAs: response.knownAs,
    })))
    .subscribe(value => {
           this.toastr.success("Logged In Successfully", "", { 
                  positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
           this.route.navigateByUrl('/splashPagePost');
     })
```

Comment: I continue to get errors saying username does not exist in type object.  Is there to say the response is of type JSON? or do I need to convert it somehow.

Comment: The reason you see errors are because Typescript does not explicitly know the type of response. Hence you have to specify the type which contains the `username`. I have altered the answer to add the type. Adding this should fix the error.